# Eclipse - combining Freemarker and HTML content assist / code completion for .ftl files

Tags: html, eclipse, freemarker, code-completion

We use .ftl files to create templates in Eclipse. Content assist for FreeMarker is working nicely thanks to the freemarker eclipse plugin but I can't figure out, how to also have HTML assist in those .ftl files. (If I use .html files I don't get FreeMarker). Is this even possible? I can add .ftl fiels to the content type HTML but that will deactivate freemarker again...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not currently possible the way that the freemarker plugin is created.  In order to get freemarker support in a .html file, a new plugin would have to be written to extend the structured source editing framework (which HTML editor is built off of) and add the freemarker extensions. To my knowledge this type of integration has not been done for freemarker.